# Increasing not initialize array value in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hy 
I have a foreach loop that adds array keys to another array. I wanted to know if it' safe to increment (with ++) and uninitialize element.
At the moment my code is:

```
foreach($SociBdP as $id=>$socio)
{
    if(!isset($provenienza[$option_name]))
        $provenienza[$option_name]=0;
    $provenienza[$option_name]++;
}
```

I wanted to know if it's safe to do

```
foreach($SociBdP as $id=>$socio)
{
    $provenienza[$option_name]++;
}
```

or if there is a risk (like in c++) that the default value of the array isn't 0

Comment: I assume you mean "safe" not "save"?  It is not clear in your question what the relation between the variable declared in foreach and the `$provenienza` variable is, so it is hard to give any advice.

Answer (score 6):

While it's a [documented behaviour](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) you can trust:

> It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a
> very good practice. Uninitialized variables have a default value of
> their type depending on the context in which they are used - booleans
> default to FALSE, **integers and floats default to zero**, strings (e.g.
> used in echo) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an empty
> array.

... it also prevents you from taking benefit of notices since you need to lower down your [error reporting](http://php.net/error_reporting) settings so they don't show up in the development phase:

```
var_dump($foo);
```

```
Notice: Undefined variable: foo in D:\tmp\borrame.php on line 3
NULL
```

Notices are often seen as an annoyance by newcomers but they're actually a terrific tool to spot silly typos.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP 7, we can use the "null coalescing operator" (??) :

```
$provenienza[$option_name] = ($provenienza[$option_name] ?? 0) + 1;
```

It is much simpler and with less "repetition" than using isset()

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the correct one is:

```
foreach($SociBdP as $id=>$socio)
{
    if(!isset($provenienza[$option_name]))
        $provenienza[$option_name]=0;
    $provenienza[$option_name]++;
}
```

You have to be sure that the array contains the key before you increment it.