# Trying to push to a three-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, push

I am trying to push to a three-dimensional array, but having trouble.

```
$players = array(
    array("player1", array(0,1,2,1,2,1), array(0,1,3,4,6,7)
    ),
    array("player2", array(0,3,2,3,1,2), array(0,3,5,8,9,11)    
    ),
    array("player3", array(0,2,3,1,2,3), array(0,2,5,6,8,11)
    )
);

$roundNumber = 5;


function addScore($playerNumber, $playerScore){

    array_push(($players[$playerNumber][1]), $playerScore);

    $nextTotalScore = $playerScore + $players[$playerNumber][2][$roundNumber];

    $players[$playerNumber][$playerNumber][2][$roundNumber] = $nextTotalScore;

}

addScore(0,5);
```

I am trying to have a three-dimensional array that holds player name, then an array for a round score, then an array for total score. It seems to not recognize $players[$playerNumber][1] as an array. I am getting the following warning pointing to that line:

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

I am not sure how else I am supposed to call my intended array. Should I even be using the push function?

Comment: I suggest you need to add 'global $players, $roundNumber;' inside your 'addScore' function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increasing not initialize array value in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240213/increasing-not-initialize-array-value-in-php)

Comment: Wouldn't `$players[$playerNumber][$playerNumber][2][$roundNumber] = $nextTotalScore` make it a 4-dimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass $players to your function.

```
$players = array(
    array("player1", array(0,1,2,1,2,1), array(0,1,3,4,6,7)
    ),
    array("player2", array(0,3,2,3,1,2), array(0,3,5,8,9,11)
    ),
    array("player3", array(0,2,3,1,2,3), array(0,2,5,6,8,11)
    )
);

$roundNumber = 5;


function addScore($players, $playerNumber, $playerScore){

    array_push(($players[$playerNumber][1]), $playerScore);

    $nextTotalScore = $playerScore + $players[$playerNumber][2][$roundNumber];

    $players[$playerNumber][$playerNumber][2][$roundNumber] = $nextTotalScore;

    return $players;

}

$players = addScore($players, 0,5);
```

That would give you other errors, such as RoundNumber being undefined. But, if you just learned something you will get it. Also, try to find a clearer way for you array key names. Playing with numeric indexes is dangerous.

Comment: awesome. thanks for your input. seemed like having the return is crucial. I added another variable equal to $GLOBALS['roundNumber'] within my function and it worked.

Comment: I would also suggest avoiding global variables as much as you can. There are better practices.